# D3 force layout: individually positioning first and last node

Tags: d3.js, position, nodes, force-layout

I would like to create a static force-directed layout as the one in this example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667139, but with the first and last node anchored on each side of the window (contrary to the example, my graph is not circular). This way I could clearly see where the graph starts and ends and also hopefully be able to give it a more linear conformation. 
So far I have attempted to assign different classes to these two nodes and then give those classes fixed coordinates, like:

```
svg.select(".first")
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return 10; })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return height/2; })

svg.select(".last")
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return width-10; })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return height/2; })
```

But it doesn't seem to be working, the two nodes are just sitting in the upper right corner of the window. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing the following code between the `for` loop and `force.stop()` seemed to work fine for me.

```
var nodes = force.nodes();
nodes[0].x = 10;
nodes[0].y = height/2;

nodes[nodes.length-1].x = width-10;
nodes[nodes.length-1].y = height/2;
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jd08of7r/) showing this. You might also want to look into the `fixed` property, which could help with the behaviour you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you, this is indeed a smart solution. However the rest of the nodes don't get affected by this: e.g. the second node remains where it would be anyways, it doesn't get pulled towards the left side. Any ideas how to fix that, so that they layout looks a bit more natural?

Comment: @Balloon [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jd08of7r/2/). In this one, the nodes are positioned and fixed before the layout is initialized, which is less likely to cause problems (and fixing after initializing isn't as simple). Also added the `gravity` parameter to the layout initialization. Default is `0.1`, reducing it causes more spread. When left at default the fixed nodes are fairly distant, but whether you change this or not would depend on how you want it to be laid out.